# How to create two separate jar files with a single build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I was trying to create two separate jar files with a single build.gradle.

It is almost working but one will overwrite the other.  What's the right way of doing it?

```
jar {
       //include contents of output dir
       from "$buildDir/classes/main"
       exclude '**/a1/**'
       archiveName "X1-1.0.0.jar"
}

jar {
       //include contents of output dir
       from "$buildDir/classes/main"
       exclude '**/a2/**'
       archiveName "X2-1.0.0.jar" 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than configuring the same Jar task twice, you need to use two Jar tasks. Assuming you are using the `java` plugin, you can reuse the Jar task named `jar` added by that plugin, and add another one yourself:

```
// reconfigure the Java plugin's `jar` task
jar {
    exclude '**/a1/**'
    baseName = 'X1'
}

// need to configure this one from scratch
task x2jar(type: Jar) {
    // referring to the output in this way
    // allows Gradle to infer task dependencies automatically
    from sourceSets.main.output 

    exclude '**/a2/**'
    baseName = 'X2'
}

// one way to make `gradle build` run both Jar tasks
assemble.dependsOn(x2jar)
```

For details on the configuration options, refer to the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: I tried. It didn't create X2.jar. I changed the line baseName = 'X2' to archiveName 'X2.jar'. It didn't work either. ;=(

Comment: Changed assemble.dependsOn(x2jar) to jar.dependsOn(x2jar). Now it worked. Thanks !

Comment: Either you didn't run `gradle build`, or you have a non-standard build. `jar.dependsOn(x2jar)` is somewhat of a hack because the two tasks aren't actually dependent on each other.

Comment: Actually running gradle build didn't help. It only produced an empty jar with      0 Thu Dec 05 07:07:34 MST 2013 META-INF/
    25 Thu Dec 05 07:07:34 MST 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
. The gradle I am using is a straight download from www.gradle.org. After I changed assemble.dependsOn(x2jar) to jar.dependsOn(x2jar). It worked fine with gradle build. It produced the exact jar with the contents I wanted.